# Connect firebird database with codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, firebird

So, I have to connect to a firebird database. I inserted [this driver](https://github.com/cgarciagl/Firebird-for-Codeigniter) on my system/database directory but my code doesn't establish a connection. It doesn't get in the controller, It quit at some point in the connection. The worst part is that It doesn't even show an error. It's all blank. :/

My database config:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = MyIp;
$db['default']['username'] = 'MyUser';
$db['default']['password'] = 'myPass';
$db['default']['database'] = 'D:\folder\file.gdb';
$db['default']['port']      = 3050;
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'firebird';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;    
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

There's something wrong with my configs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. My lampp wasn't able to use the interbase.so, which is necessary to run the firebird ( ibase_connect function ), so I instaled the apache2. Since I can get the "interbase.so", now I can connect just fine. Btw, I'm running on Ubuntu.

Well, this is It. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Codeigniter version 3

```
    $db['firebird'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'sysdba',
        'password' => 'masterkey',
        'database' => 'C://database.GDB',
        'dbdriver' => 'ibase',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'ANSI',
        'dbcollat' => 'NONE',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create alias name for your database on alias.conf or database.conf
```

mydb on localhost  = c:\path\to\db.fdb

$active_record = true;

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'SYSDBA';
$db['default']['password'] = 'masterkey';
$db['default']['database'] = 'dbname on localhost';
$db['default']['port']     = '3050';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'ibase';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = true;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = true;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = false;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = true;
$db['default']['stricton'] = true;
```